# Texturing a triangulated terrain without redrawing vertices

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, triangulation, terrain

I am making a program do display a 3D textured terrain. I`m having some performance issues. I am drawing the terrain and texturing it at the same time ->

```
void Triangle::drawTriangle( int showTexture){

if (textureId!=0 && showTexture) glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);    // Select Our Texture

glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
    if (textureId!=0 && showTexture)
         glTexCoord2d(((Point3DTexturable*)p1)->getU(), ((Point3DTexturable*)p1)->getV());
    glVertex3d(p1->getX(), p1->getY(), p1->getZ());

    if (textureId!=0 && showTexture)
           glTexCoord2d(((Point3DTexturable*)p2)->getU(), ((Point3DTexturable*)p2)->getV());
    glVertex3d(p2->getX() , p2->getY(), p2->getZ());

    if (textureId!=0 && showTexture)
           glTexCoord2d(((Point3DTexturable*)p3)->getU(), ((Point3DTexturable*)p3)->getV());
    glVertex3d(p3->getX() , p3->getY() , p3->getZ());
glEnd();
```

}

Using this method, every time i draw a new triangle i repeat the two vertices of the one next to it.
How can i draw a textured terrain without having to repeat the vertice of triangles every time?

Comment: You would benefit of using modern OpenGL. You are using deprecated functions that should not be used unless it is absolutely necessary. Google glDrawArrays or glDrawElements.

Answer (score 1):

Vertex indexing. Most of your example is no longer valid opengl. I would recommend learning modern opengl, since it seems as though you're concerned about efficiency. This will allow you to actually index vertices, and tell opengl what vertex you want to draw and when.

As Jean-Simon says, look up glDrawArrays, glDrawElements and buffer objects.